# in $R^2$, let $L$ be the line $y = mx$ where $m$ is not zero. find an expression for $T(x,y)$ where $T$ is the reflection of $R^2$ about $L$

Tags: linear-algebra, reflection

i have no idea how to start this problem. there's an example in my book and i've tried to adapt it, but i haven't been able to get very far and i'm not even sure i'm on the right track.

i know i need an expression $T(a,b)$ for any $(a,b)$ in $R^2$.

i want to set the basis $A = \{(1,0), (0,1)\}$, but i'm unsure of how to calculate the values of $T(a,b)$ using these. i think $T(1,0)=(1,mx)$ and $T(0,1)=(0,0)$, but i don't think that this is right.

have i chosen the right basis $A$? if not, how can i find a better one? and how can i calculate the values of $T(a,b)$ using the correct basis? then how should i proceed? my book and lecture content are both unclear about this.

thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: Hint: Consider a basis such that one basis vector lies on $L$, and the other basis vector is orthogonal to $L$. Then use change of basis transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the notations; I have switched $(x,y)$ and $(a,b)$.

Hint: $T(x,y)=(a,b)$ is characterized by two properties:

a) The line joining $(x,y)$ and $(a,b)$ is orthogonal to the given line. This gives $m\frac {y-b} {x-a}=-1$.

b) The mid-point of the line joining $(x,y)$ and $(a,b)$ lies on the given line. This gives $\frac {b+y} 2 =m \frac {x+a} 2$.

Now solve the two equations above for $a$ and $b$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ that will give you the formula for $T(x,y)$,

Comment: i got $T(x,y)=((b+y)/m - x, m(x+a)-y)$ because those are the values of $a$ and $b$ that i found respectively. but each term has $a$ or $b$ in it so i'm not sure i followed your last direction correctly.

Comment: @qwerty Use the first equation to write $b=y+m(x-a)$. Put this value of $b$ in the second equation. You will get $a$ completely in terms of $m$, $ x$ and $y$. Go back to $b=y+m(x-a)$ and you now have $(a,b)$ completely in terms of $m$, $ x$ and $y$. That will be your answer.

Comment: ah! thank you. i can't believe i didn't think of that.

Comment: should i be using $(b+y)/2=m(x+a)/2$ from part b of your answer to derive $b=y+m(x-a)$? if so i keep getting $b=m(x+a)-y$. i have also tried with the formula from part a but this doesn't give the right answer either.

Comment: $b=y+m(x-a)$ comes from part a). @qwerty

Comment: using part a) i get $b=(x-a)/m + y$ and $a=m(y-b)+x$. and putting this definition of b into that definition of a just returns a=a. @_@

Comment: @qwerty Sorry, I should have written $b=y+\frac  1 m(x-a)$ in my last comment. But the idea is to treat $x$ and $y$ as known, find $b$ in terms of $a,m,x,y$ from part a)$ and use b) to complete the computation.

Comment: okay, i've gotten $a=(x+2my-m^2x)/(1+m^2)$ and $b=x-y+(x+2my-m^2x)/(1+m^2)$. i guess this implies $T(x,y)=(a,b)=((x+2my-m^2x)/(1+m^2), x-y+(x+2my-m^2x)/(1+m^2))$?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, this linear transformation is determined completely by how it acts on two basis elements. But you don't have to check specifically for the standard basis! It would be wise to think, geometrically, which vectors would be best.

Note that a reflection about an axis keeps the axis in place, and so it would make things easy to choose one of the basis elements to lie on the axis of reflection (since we know that $T$ does not affect it). So we can already say that $T((1,m))=(1,m)$ (since this vector is on the axis of reflection).

Moreover, if $v$ is orthogonal to the axis of reflection, then $T$ will send it ot $-v$. So pick such a vector, such as $(-m,1)$. Now you can say that $T((-m,1))=(m,-1)$.

Since you know how $T$ acts on two basis elements, you can find a general formula for $T$. Let me know if you're having trouble with that.

Comment: i think i see how you got $T(1,m)=(1,m)$. this is given by the formula $y=mx$ because when $x=1$ then $y=m$. but i'm having a bit of trouble with $T(-m,1)$. by the definition of reflection when calculating the reflection of a given vector, is it just $f(v)=-v$ where $f$ gives the reflected vector? also, how did you pick these vectors? i guess the first one is on $L$ and the second is on the reflection of $L$ and i need one on each line? sorry for asking so many questions in one message.

Comment: The vector (-m,1) is orthogonal to the axis of reflection, since any vector on this axis is of the form (x,mx), and you can check that the scalar product of this vector and each vector on the axis is 0. The reflection does not send ANY vector v to -v, only those perpendicular to the axis of reflection (try drawing some examples to see why). I chose the vectors because as I said, it is relatively easy to see how a reflection acts on the axis of reflection and on the vectors perpendicular to it, so I chose vectors specifying this condition.